# Do I get normal achievements while playing hardcore?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Do I get normal achievements while playing hardcore?

Like reaching level 60 with two demon hunters? One in normal and one in hardcore, so that I get the "Disciples of the night" achievement (two level 60 demon hunters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, any achievement that works in normal works in hardcore too. They might be a lot harder to pull of though.

If you never beat act II in normal, then beat act I and II in hardcore you'll get the achievements for beating the Act II boss + the hardcore achievement for beating the Act II boss. And any other achievement you would have gotten if you played normal instead of hardcore.